# Problema con la paginacion de dataTable Ajax laravel

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, datatables

Tengo un inconveniente con la paginacion en dataTable Ajax (server side) en laravel 9, he realizo mi funcion donde lleno los datos haciendo la peticion ajax hacia mi tabla y tambien para realizar busqueda, en total tengo 12 registros en mi BD; pero cuando carga los datos me muestra de frente todos los registros, cuando deberia solo traer los 10 primeros y asi en la siguiente pagina (2) los dos registros faltantes.

Este es mi codigo Js con dataTable y Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    tableOrder = $('#myTableOrder').DataTable({        
        dom: 'rtip',             
        paging: true,
        //processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
            console.log(data);            
            $.get('/orden/list', {
                cod_document: $('#filter_cod_document').val(),
                business: $('#filter_business').val(),
                start_date: $('#filter_start_date').val(),
                expected_date: $('#filter_expected_date').val(),
                status: $('#filter_status').val(),
            }, function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                listOrder = [];
                res.data.forEach(element => {
                    listOrder[element.id] = element;
                });
                callback({
                    recordsTotal: res.total,
                    recordsFiltered: res.total,
                    data: res.data
                });
            })
        },

        dataSrc: 'data',
        language: {

            "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo": "Registros del _START_ al _END_ del total de _TOTAL_",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sSearch": "Buscar:",
            "sUrl": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Primero",
                "sLast": "Último",
                "sNext": "Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }

        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'cod_document' },
            { data: 'business' },
            { data: 'requested' },
            { data: 'phone' },
            { data: 'delivery_place' },
            {
                data: function (data) {
                    return formatoFecha(data.start_date);
                }
            },
            {
                data: function (data) {
                    return formatoFecha(data.expected_date);
                }
            },
            {
                data: function (data) {
                    if (data.end_date == null) {
                        return "Por confirmar"
                    }
                    else {
                        return formatoFecha(data.end_date);
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                data: function (data) {
                    if (data.status == 1) {
                        return '<div class="badge bg-warning text-dark mt-2">Registrado</div>';
                    }
                    else if (data.status == 2) {
                        return '<div class="badge bg-primary mt-2">En Proceso</div>';
                    }
                    else {
                        return '<div class="badge bg-success mt-2">Finalizado</div>';
                    }
                }

            },
            {
                data: function (data) {
                    return '<div> <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm mr-1" id="order_id" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#order-edit-modal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Editar registro" onclick="edit_order(' + data.id + ')"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar registro" onclick="delete_order(' + data.id + ')"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></div>'
                }
            },

        ]
    });
});
```

Esta es mi funcion en el controller donde traigo la data:

```
public function listorders(Request $request){      
       
        $orders = Order::query()
                        ->when($request->cod_document, fn($query, $cod_document) 
                        => $query->where('cod_document','like','%'.$cod_document.'%'))
                        ->when($request->business, fn($query, $business) 
                        => $query->where('business','like','%'.$business.'%'))
                        ->when($request->start_date, fn($query, $start_date) 
                        => $query->where('start_date', $start_date.'%'))
                        ->when($request->expected_date, fn($query, $expected_date) 
                        => $query->where('expected_date', $expected_date))
                        ->when($request->status, fn($query, $status) 
                        => $query->where('status','like','%'.$status.'%'))
                        ->orderby('cod_document')
                        ->paginate(10);

        return response()->json($orders);     
    }
```

Si pudieran ayudarme a darle solucion a la paginacion porque hasta el momento me muestra todos los registro en la primera vista y los botones no estan funcionando. Gracias